# Not receiving all response headers in middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently developing an API in .NET 5 and need to add request and response logging to the API. I am able to log the request body and headers easily. I am also able to log the response body without issue. Problem that comes in is when I want to log the response headers. I am currently only able to access `Content-Length` and `Content-Type`.

When looking in Postman for the response on the request I am receiving:

- `Date`
- `Content-Type`
- `Server`
- `Content-Length`
- `X-Rate-Limit-Limit`
- `X-Rate-Limit-Remaining`
- `X-Rate-Limit-Reset`

The `X-Rate-Limit-` is middleware in the application. I have tried to add my middleware above and below this middleware in `Startup.cs` none of which returned those headers. I have a feeling it is how I am managing the response object in the middleware when the request is created.

Here is what my middleware looks like:

```
namespace X.API.Middleware
{
    public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Request delegate that allows us to move the middleware along
        /// </summary>
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor for DI
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="next"></param>
        public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }
        
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            //Enable buffering so that the streams can be read
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

            //Read the request body to a string for logging
            var requestBodyString = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            //Read the request headers
            var requestHeaders = context.Request.Headers.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
            
            //Log the incoming request
            LogContext.PushProperty("RequestBody", requestBodyString);
            LogContext.PushProperty("RequestHeaders", requestHeaders);
            Log.Information("Incoming Request");

            //Reset the position of the request body so it doesn't seem read
            context.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            //Create a new body to be used
            var originalBody = context.Response.Body;
            await using var newBody = new MemoryStream();
            context.Response.Body = newBody;
            
            //Calls the next middleware
            await _next(context);
            
            //Seeks the body back
            newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //Read the response body string
            var responseBodyString = await new StreamReader(context.Response.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            //Read the response headers
            var responseHeaders = context.Response.Headers.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);

            //Check if the URL is not a documentation URL
            if (!context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("api-docs") && !context.Request.Path.ToString().Contains("swagger"))
            {
                //Reset custom props
                LogContext.Reset();
                //Log the response
                LogContext.PushProperty("ResponseBody", responseBodyString);
                LogContext.PushProperty("ResponseHeaders", responseHeaders);
                Log.Information("Outgoing Response");
            }
            
            //Return the original body
            newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            await newBody.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
        }
    }
}
```

And the middleware registration in `Startup.cs` is as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ApiContext context) {

    app.UseRequestResponseLogging();

    //Enable rate limiting
    app.UseIpRateLimiting();

    app.UseExceptionHandler(errorApp => errorApp.Run(ExceptionHandler.HandleException()));

    app.UseSwagger();

    app.UseReDoc(c => {
        c.DocumentTitle = "Curo API Documentation";
        c.SpecUrl = "/swagger/v1/swagger.json";
    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });

    Log.Information("Application started!");
}
```

The middleware in question is `UseRequestResponseLogging`. I have tried placing the middleware at the top and bottom with no difference between them as I believe the request and response would already have been set by then.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way of doing this by hooking into `Response.OnStarting`. I can access all the headers there; I believe that it is the last event/hook called before sending the final headers to the client. Code as follows:

```
context.Response.OnStarting((state) => {
    var headers = context.Response.Headers.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}, null!);
```